# Where do I put client-side Authentication code for an App on Facebook? In my Canvas URL HTML Document?

Tags: facebook, authentication

I have an app that I want to utilize as a facebook app. I have set up the app and now need to know where I would put the authentication code. The following code (below) is the example I have found in the documentation. This client-side example was put into the body of my HTML file and works, however, it creates an additional pop-up window with my app in it (in addition to the one on the facebook canvas).

Where should this code exist? What is the proper place? Are there parts of this code that are making the extra pop-up window? Thank you in advance.

```
     <html> 
   <head> 
     <title>Client Flow Example</title> 
   </head> 
   <body> 
   <script> 
     function displayUser(user) {
       var userName = document.getElementById('userName');
       var greetingText = document.createTextNode('Greetings, '
         + user.name + '.');
   userName.appendChild(greetingText);
     }

     var appID = YOUR_APP_ID;
     if (window.location.hash.length == 0) {
       var path = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?';
   var queryParams = ['client_id=' + appID,
     'redirect_uri=' + window.location,
     'response_type=token'];
   var query = queryParams.join('&');
   var url = path + query;
   window.open(url);
     } else {
       var accessToken = window.location.hash.substring(1);
       var path = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?";
   var queryParams = [accessToken, 'callback=displayUser'];
   var query = queryParams.join('&');
   var url = path + query;

   // use jsonp to call the graph
       var script = document.createElement('script');
       script.src = url;
       document.body.appendChild(script);        
     }
   </script> 
   <p id="userName"></p> 
   </body> 
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quickly looking over your code, you would want to drop in your APP ID as defined in the developer console for your app (e.g. facebook.com/developers). I would suggest checking out the following resources as I've found them to be extremely helpful.

Outlines recent changes to OAuth 2.0 w/ permissions:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/

Facebook JS SDK:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Comment: I've replaced the ID in the code I used but left it as is for the purpose of this post. Thank you for the Java SKD update, I was looking for that after the initial update article I read stated that it would be available at a later time.